# How to possible make use of .serialize and combine "sets" of inputs into specific groups?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, serialization

Ok, so I'm not sure the best way to even begin to find an answer to this. So the question might seem confusing.

Here's the deal. I would like to make use of an API I've written that is dependent on on multiple "child items" in order to create certain totals.

Thus I want to build a UI where "item input rows" are created dynamically (not hard, done that), BUT I want to be able to ajax those sets of rows, with their inputs in a manner similar too:

```
{
    item01:
        input1: value,
        input2: value
    item02:
        input1: value,
        input2: value
.....
```

My first thought, of course was to use `[]` on the input names to provide for multiple passings of inputs with same name, as each row will have the same inputs. However, this won't provide the POST format I want as each post item will be an array of each input via that inputs name. This means more work making sure everything is associated with the correct item row upon returning results (as there are individual results as well as the total).

So has anyone done anything similar to what I hope to achieve? Any idea how I can group inputs into individual objects within one large POST object before serializing?

### Sample HTML

```
<div id="Items" class="row">
    <fieldset class="fieldset-item ui-corner-all">
        <legend><p>Item</p></legend>
        <fieldset class="fieldset-item-input ui-corner-all">
            <legend><p>Input</p></legend>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><div>In 1</div></th>
                        <th><div>In 2</div></th>
                        <th><div>In 3</div></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div><input name="in1" type="text" class="text-center ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div></td>
                        <td><div><input name="in2" type="text" class="text-center ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></div></td>
                        <td><div><input name="in3" type="text" class="text-center ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="fieldset-item-output ui-corner-all ui-corner-all">
            <legend><p>Output</p></legend>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><div>Out 1</div></th>
                        <th><div>Out 2</div></th>
                        <th><div>Out 2</div></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><div><input name="out1" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="text-center ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div></td>
                        <td><div><input name="out2" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="text-center ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div></td>
                        <td><div><input name="out3" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="text-center ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"></div></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset-item ui-corner-all">
        ...etc...
</div>
```

[Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/2BDzv/)

Comment: Generate a json string in the structure you want and post that jsonstring instead, decode it on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I found a solution I like

I simply go through each row before submission and make a serial array of the inputs in that row, then add them to a data object to be submitted! Works like a charm!

```
$(document).on('blur change keyup', '#Items .fieldset-item-input input, #Items .fieldset-item-input select', function(e) {
    var submitData = {},
        $input = $(this).closest('.fieldset-item').find('.fieldset-item-input'),
        $output = $(this).closest('.fieldset-item').find('.fieldset-item-output');

    //  here is the key factor that helped!
    //  here i make a serial array of each items inputs
    //  and then add that array to a data object to be
    //  submitted with ajax! WORKS GREAT!
    $('#Items .fieldset-item').each(function(i) {
        submitData[i] = $(this).children('.fieldset-item-input').serializeArray();
    });

    $.ajax({
        data: submitData,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        url: $.myURL('v2', 'quote', 'calc'),
        beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) { /*console.log(settings.data);*/ $output.find('input').val(''); },
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```